# Permalink issue after adding wordpress website live

Tags: php, wordpress, migration, permalinks

We got an permalink issue after adding a wordpress website live (from dev to live website I mean)

I got this error line on all pages except the welcome page :

```
Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: quantifier does not follow a repeatable item at offset 1 in /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxx.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/class-wp.php on line 223

Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: quantifier does not follow a repeatable item at offset 1 in /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxx.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/class-wp.php on line 224
```

I f I go to setting/permalinks and I change for plain, error lines are not showing anymore. But if I go back to post name or custom structure and save these options, problem come back...

Could you help me with this issue? Everything was working good on dev...I don t understand what happened after the live migration...

Thx for your help.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to change url in .htaccess file, check if there is folder written.
2. Change old url to new url in database, here is the way you can do with query:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.oldurl', 'http://www.newurl') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.oldurl','http://www.newurl');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.oldurl', 'http://www.newurl');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'http://www.oldurl','http://www.newurl');
```